Having a problem printing out directories after using FilenameFilter interface
I am trying to print out my directories contained within a particular directory called "Books". I am using a FilenameFilter interface to filter for directories only excluding files. My code is as below:
package dirspkg;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class DirectoryDemo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        File directory = new File("C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books");

        Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return dir.isDirectory() && dir.getName().startsWith("j");
            }
        }))).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

The code is not outputting anything but I actually have directories beginning with "j" in the books directory. I simply want the directories beginning with the letter "j". What am I doing wrong?

Your 2 snippets are identical. Please edit the question.

Edited. Sorry about that.

You are using FilenameFilter in a wrong way. dir points to "C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books" and name to the entries. You are not looking at name at all.

You are using FilenameFilter in a wrong way. dir points to "C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books" and name to the entries. You are not looking at name at all.
This would give you sth akin to:
Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> {
    var testedFile = new File(dir, name);
    return testedFile.isDirectory() && name.startsWith("j");
}))).forEach(System.out::println);

Note that File.isDirectory may be slow (and it goes against the intention of FilenameFilter which should test only filenames)
New File APIs improve both

the readibility, by giving you the attributes you need to test
the speed (but measure if you care about it). See  See How to retrieve a list of directories QUICKLY in Java?

Path dir = Paths.get("C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books");

BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> dirStartingWithJ = (path, attrs)
                -> attrs.isDirectory() && path.getFileName().toString().startsWith("j");
try (Stream<Path> dirs = Files.find(dir, 1, dirStartingWithJ)) {
    dirs.forEach(System.out::println);
}


It's always a good idea to carefully read the javadoc. Also, debugging is a thing - all you needed to do to figure this one out is to print the value of name in your filter, or set a breakpoint there.
The reason it's not working: Absolute paths
As per the javadoc of listFiles: The getName() response includes the whole path. So, the string would be C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books/journey by moonlight. Which does not start with a lowercase j.
To fix it
Toss this code in the bin. java.io.File is obsolete (as in, deprecated - do not use. Java core libs don't add @Deprecated to their own deprecated stuff for somewhat dubious reasons. Point is: Just because it isn't marked @Deprecated does not mean it isn't deprecated).
The new API is in java.nio.file.Files. That's what you want to use. It clarifies this whole absolute path business (it's based on Path objects which have much clearer methods for 'I just want the simple file name' and 'I want the whole path'), and unlike java.io.File, it reports errors in a sane fashion (by throwing, instead of returning false which is easy to miss and means there's no way to know what is wrong). It also is far more feature rich - you can work with softlinks, it is aware of filesystems, and so forth.

I will look into the java.nio.file.Files API. Thanks.

Uh ok. Just re-ran the code and added a print statement in the accept method of the FilenameFilter interface. getName returns the file/directory name not the absolute path... Still i will try the alternative API you suggested.

I'd give that a shot first, and if it's still not working after a rewrite, file a new question - that way, we have the full toolkit of the Files API, and don't have to deal with the weirdness the old one has. But, I'd spend some time debugging first, usually faster than writing up a question on SO :) - good luck!

@rzwitserloot Not your usual detailed response as string isn't using absolute path C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books/journey by moonlight. It's not working because accept is called with dir=new File("C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books") and name = "journey by moonlight", and OP is testing whether parent dir is a directory and using dir.getName() rather than name - hence fails as test is "Books".startsWith("j")

Here is an answer that uses the java.nio.file package:
package dirspkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class DirectoryDemo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Path.of("C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books");
        try {
            Files.find(path, 2, (dirPath, attrs) -> attrs.isDirectory()
                    && dirPath.getFileName().toString().startsWith("j")).forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Works fine. Willing to hear other opinions on the code. It is basically the code written by one of the contributors (@Lesiak I believe)

Or just accept Lesiak's answer, see What should I do when someone answers my question

Accepted.... :)

@DuncG you criticized my answer though, which is why I felt the need to write it, the way he proposed...

I greatly appreciate the contributions. Below is the code I used to solve the problem. Please feel free to critique or point out any inefficiencies.
package dirspkg;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DirectoryDemo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
// Get file handle for Books directory
        File directory = new File("C:/users/Dell/Desktop/Books");

// Create stream from array of File objects contained in Books directory
// that have been filtered for directories whose name begin with the letter 'j' 
// and print the name of those directories out via the stream
        Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    // Check that for each file object in Books directory that it is a 
    // directory and its name begins with the letter 'j'
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                Path path = Paths.get(dir + "\\" + name);
                return Files.isDirectory(path) && path.getFileName().toString().startsWith("j");
            }
        }))).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

My output is as below:
C:\users\Dell\Desktop\Books\java books
C:\users\Dell\Desktop\Books\javascript
C:\users\Dell\Desktop\Books\julia programming

Which are the sub-directories in the Books directory that begin with the letter 'j'. I am open to any critique and better suggestions. Thanks.

Nothing to correct, good job!

You've mixed use of File and NIO Path/Files. You would be better off with staying all java.io if you have to keep dependency on File, or preferably use all java.nio code as suggested by rzwitserloot and in Lesiak improved answer (Files.find with depth = 1)

Will try to do that @DuncG, thanks. Will post another answer, which you could critique as well.
